# Solve discrete logarithm, $a^x = b \bmod 2^N$ by p-adic logarithm

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, modules, p-adic-number-theory

I want to find the smallest solution, $x$, for
$$a^x = b \bmod 2^N$$
by using [p-adic logarithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_exponential_function).

We suppose $a \bmod 4 =1$ and $b \bmod 4 = 1$. Another case can be solved easily or converted to $a, b \bmod 4 = 1$ case.
For $a \bmod 4=1$, and $b \bmod 4 = 1$, p-adic logarithm can be defined as you can find in the link above. Then by using 2-adic logarithm, $x$ can be write as
below.
$$x = \frac{\log{b}}{\log{a}}$$
However, this solution is not always the smallest solution.
For example, let's consider the problem,
$$5^x = 9 \bmod 16$$
by using 2-adic logarithm.
Since $9\bmod 4 = 1$ and $5\bmod 4=1$, 2-adic logarithm can be defined for $9$ and $5$. Then $x = \log(9) / \log(5)$ . Let's calculate the $\log{9}$ and $\log{5}$ by formal power series.
$$\log(1 + 8) = 8 - (1/2) 8^2 + ... = 8$$
$$\log(1 + 4) = 4 - (1/2) 4^2 + ... = -4 = 12$$
Then, $\log(9) / \log(5) = 2 / 3$. Since $3$ is coprime to $16$, inverse of $3$, $3^{-1}=11 \bmod 16$,  can be found by extended euclidean algorithm (or by expanding $1/3=1-2+2^2-2^3+2^4-...$). Then, $x=2/3=2\times 11=6 \bmod \phi(16)$. Here, $\phi(n)$ is the Euler function of $n$. We find the solution, $x=6$. Let's check this is actually the solution,
$$5^6 = 15625 = 9 \bmod 16$$.
However, this is not the smallest solution. The smallest solution of $x$ is $x=2$ as below.
$$5^2=25=9 \bmod 16$$
We can find such case infinitely. My question is, can we construct the smallest solution by using p-adic logarithm?

Comment: You need $v(b-1) \ge v(a-1)\ge 2$ then $b = a^y$ with $y= \frac{\log b}{\log a}\in \Bbb{Z}_2$ and the least integer $x$ such that $b \equiv a^x\bmod 2^N$ is the least integer such that $x\equiv y \bmod 2^{N-v(a)}$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I want to confirm that the $v(a)$ on the exponent of $2$ is the product of $v$ and $a$?

Comment: $v$ is the 2-adic valuation.... For $c\in \Bbb{Z}_2$, $v(c)$  is the least integer $l$ such that $c\equiv 0 \bmod 2^l, c\not \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{l+1}$ (it is finite except for $c=0,v(c)=\infty$). It satisfies $v(cd)=v(c)v(d),v(c+d)\ge \min(v(c),v(d))$ and $|c|= 2^{-v(c)}$ is a non-archimedian absolute value and $\Bbb{Z}_2,\Bbb{Q}_2$ are the completion (limits of Cauchy sequences) of $\Bbb{Z},\Bbb{Q}$ for it.

Comment: I understand that $v(c)$ is the number of trailing zeros of $c$.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is the set of sequences $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ with $a_n\in \Bbb{Z/2^n Z}$ and $a_{n+1}\equiv a_n \bmod 2^n$, a ring with the termwise addition and multiplication.

Comment: Maybe, I understand your statement. By binomial theorem, $a^{x+2^{N-v(a)}}=a^x$.  For $5^x = 9 \bmod 16$, $2^{N-v(a)}=4$. So, the solution, $x=6$ is actually same with $2$. Thank you for your endurance.

Comment: Yes, the $m$ such that we take $\frac{\log b}{\log a}\bmod 2^m$ is found from $(1+2^{2+r} (2s+1))^{2^t (2u+1)} \equiv 1+2^{2+r+t} \bmod 2^{2+r+t+1}$. To finish your proof you need to show : both $\log (1+t),\exp t$ converge for $v(t)\ge 2$ and $v(\log(1+t))=v(t)$ and $\exp(\log(1+t)) = 1+t$ (as formal series thus as functions) and $\log a^x= x\log a$ at first for integer $x$ and extended by continuity to $x\in \Bbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: I verify $\bmod 2^{N-v(a)}$ rule by the code. https://ideone.com/F0SOp3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just render $8/12\equiv 2/3\bmod 16$.  The denominator $12$ does not have a multiplicative inverse $\bmod 16$ and therefore the familiar rules for division do not apply.

We start with the equation

$12x\equiv 8\bmod 16$

The modulus on $x$ in the logarithmic equation is *not* the Euler totient of the modulus in the original equation, rather it is the original modulus itself, in this case $16$.  The reason for this is connected with $\log(1\pm u)$ having the same valuation as $u$ itself.  Here, $1-9/5^x$ is to be rendered with $2$-adic valuation $\le 1/16$ to satisfy the original equation $\bmod 16$, so we must have $|\log(9/5^x)|\le(1/16)$ forcing $\log 9\equiv x\log 5\bmod 16$, not just $\bmod 8$.  Similarly in an exponential equation to be satisfied $\bmod 2^n$, the logarithms must be equated $\bmod 2^n$ not $\bmod \phi(2^n)$.  The relation $|\log(1\pm u)|=|u|$ also holds $p$-adically for other primes $p$, so more generally an exponential equation $\bmod p^n$ must have a logarithmic equation also holding $\bmod p^n$.

To solve the logarithmic equation above, properly rendered $\bmod 16$, you can divide both sides by $4$ but then, you also have to divide the modulus itself by $\text{gcd}(16,4)=4$.  Thus properly,

$3x\equiv 2\bmod 4$

Thereby $x\equiv 2\bmod 4$ showing that $x=6$ is a solution but also $x=2$ is the minimal one.

This reduction in the modulus may also be rendered in $2$-adics.  When you (correctly) render the following $2$-adic logarithms

$\log 5 =...1100$

$\log 9 = ...1000$

you can then assert that

$(...1100)x=...1000$

but you cannot divide by the coefficient of $x$ because this has terminal zeroes and thus no multiplicative inverse.  You have to cancel the terminal zeroes in $...1100$ with those of $...1000$.  Fortunately the constant term $...1000$ has enough terminal zeroes to do that in $2$-adic integers, so you end with

$(...11)x=...10$

You have now enabled the division, but at the price of having only two bits to work with.  Thus you obtain $x=...10$ or, in modular arithmetic, $x\equiv 2\bmod 4$.  The cancellation required to enable the division is equivalent to reducing the modulus in the earlier treatment.

Despite this reduction, it is easily proven that the residue of $x\bmod 4$ is sufficient to fix $5^x\bmod 16$.  From the binomial theorem:

$5^{4k+2}=(4+1)^{4k+2}=\text{(binomial terms with factor 4^2=16)}+4(4k+2)+1\equiv 9\bmod 16$

thus showing that the residue of $x$ need be rendered only $\bmod 4$ to solve the original equation $\bmod 16$.

Comment: I've fixed a couple of obvious typos for you. However, about two-thirds of the way down, you have "... the constantvtefm $...1000$ has ...". I don't know what "constantvtefm" is supposed to be, so I suggest you fix that yourself.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.  My typing skills are apparently equal to one divided by my skills with modular arithmetic :-(.  Doesn't help to wirknkn a mobile device.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I agree that I should divide the modular also by the gcd.

Comment: $\phi(16)$ = 8. Dividing by the gcd of 8 and 12, the modular become 2. However, this does not produce $x=2$. Do I miss something?

Comment: The Euler totient does not directly enter; once we have rendered the logarithms we are solving a linear equation not an exponential one.

Comment: I find that I am downvoted.  I do not know what is wrong with this answer.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: I upvoted and don't understand downvotes either. It would be nice if the answer could be amended with the case of general $2^N$ or even $p^N$ instead of $16$. Comments by user reuns under the OP go in that direction.

Comment: @torsten see the paragraph Icadded.  It explains why we do not take the Euler totientof the original modulus when we set up the logarithmic equation, and since the equality that governs this applies $\bmod 2^n$ we are always using the original modulus in $2$-adics.

Comment: Dear Oscar Lanzi, thank you for addressing my question of Euler function. I verify your method by code. https://ideone.com/ycpIpg . I want to confirm that I follow your statement correctly. $\log({1 \pm u})$ have the same valuation with $u$. In other words, valuation of $\log{u}$ is same with $u-1$ and $-u+1$. So, if we apply this by $u=9/5^x$, the valuation of $\log{9/5^x}$ is same with $9/5^x-1$ and $-9/5^x+1$. Since the valuation of $9/5^x - 1$ should be equal or less than $1/16$, the valuation of $\log{9/5^x}$  should be equal or less than $1/16$. This is nothing but taking mod 16 for log.

Comment: That is right.  As an exercise you may want to try $5^x\equiv 9\bmod 256$.  You may be surprised at what happens with the logarithms and therefore with the minimal solution.

Comment: The minimal solution is $x=6$ which is what I found by incorrect way for $\bmod 16$. This is still minimal solution for $\bmod 2^5,2^6,2^7,2^8$.